# Correctly typesetting a tilde

Tags: tilde, symbols

How do I set the tilde (~) character correctly in LaTeX?

There’s a [question discussing that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256457/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex) on Stack Overflow, with a lot of answers. But dare I say it? They all suck:

- `\textasciitilde` is too high,
- `\texttildelow` is too low.
- `$\sim$` can be tweaked to look more or less acceptable: `{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\sim$}}` – but even that is a hack and uses the wrong symbol.

The point is – the tilde character is *definitely* an existing glyph in any font I am tempted to use. How can I just access and typeset *that* character, please? Without resorting to some other, similar-looking glyph that first needs to be nudged into place using a cunning combination of font size and raised boxes?

There **must** be a possibility to access that glyph directly from the font definition.

To demonstrate, look at this screenshot which attempts simply to display a C++ destructor of a type `T` (`~T`):

[image: tilde symbols]

Compare this with the symbol we get in the browser: `~` – *that*’s what I want.

Comment: I know this is already answered. But i have to point out that the tilde character (Unicode 0x7E) just so happens to have a "high" glyph in the Computer Modern font https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/computer-modern. That's a deliberate design choice for the tilde glyph. (Like how some fonts have a low J glyph.) The glyph you are looking for (to access and typeset _that_ character, which is already there) is an other font with a "middle" glyph for tilde, or to "fake" it by using \raisebox. But +1 as i don't like the default design of ~ in CM either.

Comment: Subset of [symbols - How does one insert a backslash or a tilde (~) into LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1), for cross-linking purpose.

Comment: @user202729 Ah, that's annoying: based on votes the other question/answers see a lot more traffic, yet the answers here are lot more comprehensive (and, importantly, *better*) than on the other question. (EDIT: hmm and apparently I knew that already, given that I answered the other question.)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It all depends on what do you want this glyph to stand for.

If you want to use it in an url then add `\usepackage{url}` (or `hyperref`) to your preamble and then use `\url{http://example.com/~user}`.

If you want to use it inside a math formula as some kind of relation then use `$a \sim b$`.

According to the "Comprehensive Symbols List", to get a vertically centered `~` you can use `\texttildelow` in any font *other* than Computer Modern, txfonts, and pxfonts. For example the following does the trick for typesetting a C++ destructor

```
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\texttildelow T
```

Comment: Thanks. I see now that I need to ask a new question – because this solution still doesn’t work with XeTeX in conjunction with TrueType fonts.

Comment: Uh, scratch that. For TTF/OTF fonts, `\char`\``~` works.

Answer (score 93):

Here’s a list for completeness’ sake.

If you want to typeset a URL or file path, use the [`url`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) (or [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)) package with the appropriate command and be done with. Otherwise, there are three distinct cases:

1. If you are using the standard [*Computer Modern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern) font, [`txfonts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/txfonts) or [`pxfonts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pxfonts): use DocBucket’s workaround:

   ```
   \usepackage{textcomp}
   \newcommand{\textapprox}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\texttildelow}}
   ```

   … or use Latin Modern fonts instead (see next point).
2. If you are using a [PostScript/Type1 font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#Type_1) via a package such as [`mathptmx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx) or [`lm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lm): Set the font encoding to T1 (via [`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontenc)) and use `\textasciitilde`.
3. If you are using a TTF or OTF font via XeTeX or LuaTeX: Use `` \char`~ `` to insert a tilde.

Comment: I'm using a font called iwona which I think is T1 and I can't get either \texttildelow or \char`~ to work.

Comment: Case 2 is wrong, just use `\textasciitilde` for T1 fonts, no package needed. This works with all T1 fonts, in particular with `lmodern`.

Comment: @MateusAraújo I meant to write “Type1” (see the link! — I was talking about font formats, not encodings). Indeed it works if you set the *font encoding* to T1 (which isn’t done by default; instead, OT1 is used, and the tilde looks wonky). Anyway, I’ll edit this now.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought a T1 font necessarily had to use a T1 font encoding, but this is not the case, as these two "T1" are unrelated concepts that share the same name. Anyway, it's nice of you to fix your old answer.

Answer (score 44):

This is a bug in Computer Modern. `\textasciitilde` is the correct character and should be rendered vertically centred. To fix it, the best way is to use Latin Modern with T1 encoding, as in

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\textasciitilde T
\end{document}
```

This also works with any font that I bothered to try, like `mathpazo`, `times`, `berasans`, `inconsolata`, etc.

EDIT: Rewrote answer in response to comment.

Comment: Actually this doesn’t seem to work. An MWE, loading the `article` document class, `lmodern` and trying to typeset `\textasciitilde{}T` produces the *wrong* tilde (high up).

Comment: You're right. The problem is that I have never thought about using Latin Modern with legacy enconding. You must use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to have correct results.

Comment: This solution overrides the main font of the document.

Comment: [Remark, do not use this for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470976/250119)

Answer (score 23):

None of the existing answers really do the trick for me. In particular,

- switching to another font (e.g. `{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\texttildelow}`) hurts my stickler's heart;
- using `$\sim$` doesn't look good, especially in bold typewriter;
- I'd really like a macro that typesets a vertically centred tilde regardless of the font and encoding used.

Here is a table summarising the tests I ran (mostly on TeX fonts):

[image]

The `\midtilde` macro is my attempt at typesetting a vertically centred tilde, regardless of the font being used. I haven't tested it on any other font than those listed in the table. Please let me know (in the comments) if you find fonts for which `\midtilde` doesn't produce a vertically centred tilde.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\ding{51}}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\textcolor{red}{\ding{55}}}%

\usepackage{textcomp}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\midtilde@raisedtilde[1][.5]{\raisebox{#1ex}{\texttildelow}}
\def\midtilde@normaltilde{\texttildelow}

\newcommand\midtilde%
{%
  \expandafter\in@\expandafter{\f@family}%
    {cmr,cmss,cmtt,cmm,cmsy,cmx,%
    lmr,lmss,lmtt,lmm,lmsy,lmx,%
    pxr,pxss,pxm,pxsy,pxx,%
    txr,txss,txm,txsy,txx}%
  \ifin@%
    \midtilde@raisedtilde%
  \else%
    \expandafter\in@\expandafter{\f@family}%
    {pxtt,txtt}%
    \ifin@%
      \midtilde@raisedtilde[.35]%
    \else%
      \midtilde@normaltilde%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}


\begin{document}

\section{Tests}

\newcommand\fontrow[2]{%
  \fontfamily{#1}\selectfont\f@family         &
  \fontfamily{#1}\selectfont A\texttildelow a & 
  #2                                          &
  \fontfamily{#1}\selectfont A\midtilde a      \\
}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
  \toprule
    \texttt{Font family} & A\texttt{\string\texttildelow} a & centred? & A\texttt{\string\midtilde} a \\
  \midrule
    \fontrow{cmr}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{cmss}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{cmtt}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{cmm}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{cmsy}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{cmx}{\xmark}
  \midrule
    \fontrow{lmr}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{lmss}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{lmtt}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{lmm}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{lmsy}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{lmx}{\xmark}
  \midrule
    \fontrow{pxr}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{pxss}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{pxtt}{?}
    \fontrow{pxm}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{pxsy}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{pxx}{\xmark}
  \midrule
    \fontrow{txr}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{txss}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{txtt}{?}
    \fontrow{txm}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{txsy}{\xmark}
    \fontrow{txx}{\xmark}
  \midrule
    \fontrow{ptm}{\cmark}
    \fontrow{phv}{\cmark}
    \fontrow{pcr}{\cmark}
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: After `\usepackage{newtxtext}`, `\midtilde` sits far too low in either Roman or sans-serif text.  I fixed this locally by adding `t1ntxrx` and `t1ntxss` to the longer of the two lists of font families.  But perhaps this is better handled by reporting it as a bug against the `newtxtext` package?

Comment: It fails if you load `cfr-lm`. I think it is reasonable for `cfr-lm` to follow `lmodern` by default, so if you want this to be a general solution, I think the families defined by `cfr-lm` need to be accommodated in the same way as the other CM/LM variants.

Comment: Updating my first comment above, `newtxtext` 1.4 and later has switched to using TeXGyre Termes fonts, which put me back to seeing a \midtilde that sat far too low in either Roman or sans-serif text. I fixed this locally by adding `t1ntxrj`, `t1qhv`, and `ts1qhv` to the longer of the two lists of font families.

Comment: It is a good idea anyway to not use the OT1 encoding, as it causes several other problems.

Answer (score 14):

according to the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List, `\texttildelow` "*produces a vertically centered “~” in most fonts but a baseline-oriented “~” in Computer Modern, txfonts, pxfonts, and various other fonts originating from the TEX world.*" So to produce a centered Tilde, one can use something like

```
{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\texttildelow}T()
```

(Taken from the symbol list source code. A different font might give a better result, depending on what the main font of your text is.)

Comment: a list of available font name can be found [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Font_typefaces)

Answer (score 9):

Every time I google the tilde problem, this question comes up. I cannot be the only one finding the link this way.

In that case, here's the simple fix *(edit: for the Computer Modern font)* that I cannot believe I have yet to see anywhere else. Note that most of the code below is a MWE; the fix itself is only two lines (one line if you already use `textcomp`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\newcommand{\textapprox}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\texttildelow}}
\usepackage{url}



\begin{document}

\section{Unsatisfying fixes}

Using \verb+\texttildelow{}12+ (with the \texttt{textcomp} package) gives: 
\begin{center}
My dog weighs \texttildelow{}12~kg.
\end{center}
Using \verb+\url{~12}+ (with the \texttt{url} package) gives:
\begin{center}
My dog weighs \url{~12}~kg.
\end{center}
Using \verb+$\sim$12+  gives:
\begin{center}
My dog weighs $\sim$12~kg.
\end{center}

\section{My fix}
In the preamble:
\begin{verbatim}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\newcommand{\textapprox}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\texttildelow}}
\end{verbatim}
Using \verb+\textapprox{}12+ gives:
\begin{center}
My dog weighs \textapprox{}12~kg.
\end{center}
That looks about right to me. If you want to change the height, it's easy to do so globally by tweaking the \texttt{0.5ex} value.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, `\texttildelow` by itself should work just fine with T1, no “raisebox” needed, as long as you are not using the CM font (your solution works for CM though). If you are using a TTF font, then ``\char`~`` should work. It’s not very clear but it’s written in a comment above.

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned that I was specifically talking about CM. Do most people switch into a different font? Maybe it's because I'm new to LaTeX, but I still rather like CM so I'm currently writing with it.

Comment: Well I cannot judge, I dislike the look of CM so I never use it. But my comment wasn’t meant as discouragement. This is actually a solid answer, in particular since the `lmodern` workaround, mentioned above, doesn’t work.

Answer (score 4):

This problem was also driving me crazy for typesetting code in an `lstlisting`.  I solved it with

```
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate=%
{~}{{\url{~}}}1
}
```

Most of the other answers here either don't work in a listing, or require more gymnastics than I was ready to undertake.

Comment: This even maintains the syntax highlighting of the tilde for `language = Python`, which is great! Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, I've changed my mind (sorry!) If you use the `hyperref` package, then `\url{~}` is turned into a link to `~`, which doesn't make sense, and also changes the colour of `~` in the code. Instead I now use `literate={~}{{\raisebox{-.25em}{\textasciitilde}}}{1}`.

Comment: good points; when i come back to the template using this, i'll have a re-look

Answer (score 2):

I had the same difficulties. In my case, the context was indeed an URL but the existing suggestions didn't quite work as I expected and the `\url{}` command was reducing the size of the font (making the text weird compared to the rest of the paragraph).

Then, I found [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718479/what-is-the-best-way-to-produce-a-tilde-in-latex-for-a-website#comment3107883_718484) that worked like a charm! :)

```
% [...]
\newcommand{\urlwofont}[1]{\urlstyle{same}\url{#1}}

\begin{document}

\urlwofont{http://www.site/~person}
% [...]
```