# How to type & in LaTeX?

Tags: characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Escape character in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex)

I'm trying to type the word & but I encounter with error :

> misplaced alignment tab character &

And when I put it into verbatim it will show Q&A in a seperated line!
So how should I type & in LaTeX?

Answer (score 63):

Type `\&`. This is a very basic question covered by all introductory material on LaTeX. You should consider taking a look into such an introduction (for example [lshort.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf), 1.3.2).

Comment: Going through Latex book to look this up: probably no less than 2 minutes.
Typing "latex amp" into Google and getting this answer: 10 seconds.