# Typing "&" in tables

Tags: tables, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Escape character in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex)
>   [How to type & in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36022/how-to-type-in-latex)

```
\begin{tabular}{ l | c || r | }
  A&B & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
```

How would I type `&` in LaTeX? Because I  want for example, `A&B` to be in one box, but I cant seem to figure out how.

Comment: Can you try  `\&` and let us know?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to type & in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36022/2693) which is a duplicate of [Escape character in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34580/2693).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `&` is reserved, you need to escape it using `\&`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l | c || r | }
  A\&B & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```