# Adding the character & in LaTeX table

Tags: tables, symbols, ampersand

My question is easy but I currently haven't the response.

How can I add the "&" as a normal char inside a table row?
If I try to use $&$, I have an error.

Comment: More very similar questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36022/how-to-type-in-latex, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95270/how-do-i-use-literally-in-latex, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex

Answer (score 2):

Escape it with a backslash:

```
\&
```