# Hash character in LaTeX

Tags: characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Escape character in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex)

How do you write the # character in LaTeX?

Answer (score 217):

```
\#
```

You just escape the #.

Comment: Is there another way? I've a bib manage that is not escaping a # and always wants to rebuild the bib file (so if I escape it manually, it gets regularly unescaped ):

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256553/how-can-i-get-a-better-pound-symbol-number-sign-hash-character

Comment: `\char"0023` should work if `\#` is not working (e.g. using the todonotes package)