# How to Render \bigwedge as more Inline Friendly

Tags: symbols, fontsize

I have recently started using the symbol `\bigwedge` in my TeX documents and it doesn't fit so well when used inline.

Textbooks use `\Lambda` rather that `\bigwedge` but I don't want to use `\Lambda` since it has a slightly different shape. (I guess I have some sort of a compulsive disorder in this case).

Is there a way to make `\bigwedge` fit well with the remaining text when used inline while preserving the shape and geometry of the symbol?

Comment: I am not sure why the math text is not rendering on this page. It works just fine on MSE.

Comment: In this page it shows the code only. People here wants to show the code not the output.

Comment: Do you mean that `$\bigwedge\limits_{i\in I}A_i$` is too big? You can use some trick: `\DeclareMathOperator*{\wedgein}{\wedge}` on preamble and then `$\wedgein\limits_{i\in I}A_i$`

Comment: @Sigur The `\wedge` is too small. I like to use it for `a\wedge b`. On this other hand, I like to write `\bigwedge^k V` instead of `\wedge^k V` or `\Lambda^k V`. The problem is that the legs of the `\bigwedge` hang out of the line a little bit. So does its apex.

Comment: It's normal `\bigwedge` has some depth, as `sum` has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're not interested in the operator-status of `\bigwedge` then. That is, you just want to use it as a symbol. For that, resize it to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256556/5764
\newcommand{\BigWedge}{\mathord{\adjustbox{valign=B,totalheight=.6\baselineskip}{$\bigwedge$}}}

\begin{document}

Some text $\Lambda$ and $\bigwedge$ then some more.

Some text $\Lambda$ and $\BigWedge$ then some more.

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could import `\bigwedge` from [`MnSymbol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol) (see Table 64: `MnSymbol` Variable-sized Math Operators of the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) and [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764)).

Comment: Thank you. It works for me. Though I do not understand what is meant by 'operator-status of `\bigwedge`'. Can you please explain it?

Comment: @Werner, the OP wants to use as `\bigwedge^k V`. So I think that `$ $` should be taking in care.