# Escaping in \lstinline

Tags: listings

There are several options for escaping LaTeX code in the `lstlisting`-environment. But this doesn't seem to work in `\lstinline`. I'd like to do something like this:

```
\lstinline[escapechar=§]{§\textlangle§foo§\textrangle§}
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Escaping via `mathescape` from [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) works in `\lstinline` just the same as it does in the `lstlisting` environment. Here's a minimal example showing how to use it:

[image: Escaping in \lstinline]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\begin{document}
\section{foo} \label{foo}
\lstinline[mathescape]!abc$ijk$xyz$\ref{foo}$23!
\end{document}
```

In the above example, `ijk` is set in math mode, since `mathescape` is true, while `\ref{foo}` is also, but prints as a reference to the first section. Note the delimiter choice `!` rather than `{...}`, although the MWE also works with this.

Comment: Many thanks, Werner, for the tip! But, to be in math mode when escaping is not always desirable: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{listings} \lstset{mathescape} \begin{document} \lstinline+$Hello world!$+ \end{document}` Unfortunately, I don't see another solution!

Comment: if I remove 'abc' inside the \lstinline, the above code does not work. This means the escape char $ cannot be the first character in the listing. It is so weird. I do need to have a math symbol at the beginning of the formula and thus the escape char $ must be the first char.

Comment: @AnCongTran: I have no problem when I remove `abc` since the delimiters `!`...`!` still remain intact. Yes, using `\lstinline[mathescape]$`...`$` will be weird, but it still works (using my MWE).

Comment: When using the `\text{ijk}` macro from [amsmath](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) package, you can also include normal text into math mode. So this answer can be used in a more general way, like `\lstinline[mathescape]!abc$\text{ijk}$xyz!`.

Answer (score 14):

From reading the code of the `listings` package, it is apparently deliberate but undocumented behaviour that escapes cannot be used in `lstinline`, with the exception of `mathescape`. Presumably escapes are considered an 'unsafe feature' in `TextStyle` contexts (of which `lstinline` is one), but it is not clear why or when it might be unsafe.

It is possible to re-enable the feature, as done below, but beware in case it causes any problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43526
% fix the apparently deliberate but undocumented behaviour of disabling escapes other than mathescape in TextStyle (used by \lstinline)
% there may be a good reason why this is disabled by default, so beware in case it causes any problems
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lsthk@TextStyle}{\let\lst@DefEsc\@empty}{}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\makeatother

% for the example:
\usepackage{textcomp}% for \textlangle, \textrangle


\begin{document}
Experimental brace syntax: \lstinline[escapechar=§]{§\textlangle§foo§\textrangle§}

Standard delimiter syntax: \lstinline[escapechar=§]!§\textlangle§foo§\textrangle§!

\end{document}
```

[image: Illustration of output of code]

Comment: Here's one example of problem: when inside a `{tabular}`, the width of the escaped text is not taken into account which causes overlaps with the text which follows. For example, in `\begin{tabular}{l}\lstinline[escapechar=§]{foo§bar§} text\end{tabular}`, the words `bar` and `text` overlap.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet: Thanks, good spot. Feel free to add your example to the answer. I wonder if it's worth trying to find a more satisfactory workaround for issues like that.

Comment: I really like this approach. However, I ran into trouble when using it within a macro. I posted my problem here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543286/combining-lstinline-escapes-with-a-macro It would be nice if you could check it out.