# replace text with variables

Tags: macros, listings

I created a new command to replace all references with a text:

```
\newcommand{\Version}{1.0}
```

This works well in my texts. However, it does not work in this case:

```
\begin{fullwidth} 
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=bash] 
        mv ~/Downloads/application_\Version.bin .. # comment
    \end{lstlisting} 
\end{fullwidth} endcode
```

How can I do this? The expected result should replace \Version with 1.0

Answer (score 5):

To do this you have to "escape" the listings code back to LaTeX using an `escapeinside` option to `listings`, like this:

```
\lstset{escapeinside={|}{|}}
```

then code between `||` is parsed by latex. Since vertical bar is used a lot in bash, I used the delimiters from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197509/134574):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}% Text between (*@ and @*) will be parsed by LaTeX

\newcommand{\Version}{1.0}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash] 
  mv ~/Downloads/application_(*@\Version@*).bin .. # comment
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```