# escaping inside lstlisting is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: listings

The previous answer: [listings 'escapeinside'-option is not working for me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197507/listings-escapeinside-option-is-not-working-for-me/197509)
indicated that

```
escapeinside={@*}{*@)},
```

should allow me to escape inside a listing with @* ... *@

However in my listing, everything following the escape is then treated as LaTeX not listing:

```
// remove all multiples starting with @* $i^2$ *@
for (uint64_t j = i*i; j <= n; j += 2*i)
  isPrime[j] = false;
```

so the for loop comes out wrong. If this is insufficient code, I will try to work up an MWE

Comment: Please provide a full example that others can copy and test as is. That makes it a lot easier to test and help.

Comment: ... you sure it's not a typo on your side? Search for `)` in your question.

Comment: as @user202729 mentions, removing that `)` and the example works just fine for me.

Comment: @user202729, that's the answer!