# How do I print $ in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Escape character in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex)

I have some equations where I am using `$`.But when I execute my `.tex` file with that particular equation the `$` sign disappears in the pdf.

Can someone help me regarding this.

Comment: You mean a dollar sign is part of your equation? Then escaping it with a backslash should work, shouldn't it? That is `\$`

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to quote `$` sign with backslash: `\$`

Answer (score 6):

try `$` sign with `\$`

Click  [here](http://aps.org/meetings/abstract/latex.cfm)  ...

---

[image]