# How do I use '&' literally in LaTeX?

Tags: ampersand

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)
>   [Escape character in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex)

In the `itemize` environment, how do I use the ampersand symbol `&` without `LaTeX` trying to use it as a command?

Comment: enter it as `\&`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I can't believe that I am unable to find a duplicate for it. I even wrote the tag wiki for {ampersand} which contains the "solution" already.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Is there anything other? I cannot get it work with XeLaTeX?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 -- you must have a package loaded that changes the meaning (to latex) of `\&`, but since we don't know that that might be, can't guess at an answer.  since you're not the person who asked *this* question, please post a new one, with a compilable example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 169):

How about `\&`?

This also works fine in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.
For example, in XeLaTeX this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
Testing... \&
\end{document}
```

is thus rendered:

[image]

Comment: This does not work in XeLaTeX. Maybe something there too

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영  It does.

Comment: @NVaughan I cannot get it work in my environment. Is there any more universal way without fontspec? - - This works `{\&}` instead. But it does not work inside `\textbf`.

Comment: Latex has set of symbols as a part of compilation. Such symbols one can use in the tex by \symbol.

Comment: Is it just me or is the ampersand by using `\&` too fancy? :P

Comment: It doesn't work. you get an error: "Misplaced alignment tab character &."