# Misplaced alignment tab character & error while using bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, errors

When I build my tex file, I get this error:

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.6 \newblock Chapman &
Hall/CRC, six edition, 2003.
I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark
here. If you just want an ampersand, the remedy is
simple: Just type `I\&' now. But if some right brace
up above has ended a previous alignment prematurely,
you're probably due for more error messages, and you
might try typing `S' now just to see what is salvageable.
```

my bib file looks like this:

```
@book{a1,
    author    = "Shasha, D. and Zhu, Y.",
    title     = "High Performance Discovery in Time series, Techniques and Case Studies",
    publisher = "Springer",
    year      = "2004"
 }
,
@book {a2,
 author    = "Shasha, D. and Zhu, Y.",
    title     = "High Performance Discovery in Time series, Techniques and Case Studies",
    publisher = "Springer",
    year      = "2014"
}
```

Comment: Just write "Chapman \& Hall/CRC" in the bib file, `&` is one of the special characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: relevant information: [Escape character in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34586/579)

Comment: I have deleted it, but I get still this error

Comment: Delete the `.bbl` file, run pdflatex-bibtex-pdflatex-pdflatex again.

Comment: Your sample bib file doesn't contain a `Chapman & Hall` string, so it can't be used as a starting point for providing a correct field (which will almost certainly be `Chapman \& Hall`).