# Typing the symbol "&" in place of "and"

Tags: bibliographies, symbols, characters

While writing the reference in `.bib` file, I want to mention the address of publication of the book which contains "&" symbol. While executing the `main.tex` file I am getting error as "! Misplaced alignment tab character &." The code is like

```
\documentclass{Thesis} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\label{Chapter1}
\section{description}
     This is my main text to be provided with reference\cite{Ref1}.
\label{Bibliography}
\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} 
\bibliography{Bibliography} 
\end{document}
```

and the `Bibliography.bib` is in the form

```
@book{Ref1,
    author     = " Myself",
    title          = "it's my book",
    year         = "2015",
    publisher  = " Home publication",
    address    = "At home, Smith & Johns, abc ",
}
```

Comment: probable duplicate: [Misplaced alignment tab character & error while using bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175487/579).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape your ampersand, just prepend it with a backslash like this:

```
@book{Ref1,
    author     = " Myself",
    title          = "it's my book",
    year         = "2015",
    publisher  = " Home publication",
    address    = "At home, Smith \& Johns, abc ",
}
```

To expand on this, the reserved characters in LaTeX are:

```
# $ % ^ & _ { } ~ \
```

And they should be escaped like this when you want them in text:

```
\# \$ \% \^{} \& \_ \{ \} \~{} \textbackslash{}
```

Comment: Yeah. It works properly. It's quite confusing for me to understand the variations between commanded symbols and regular symbols with backslash. But anyway thanks for your help. @Ryan.

Comment: @vis54132 See my edit