# Why does LaTeX throw an error when I write _ in text mode

Tags: tex-core

Why LaTex return error when I write `_` in normal mode (not math mode). Why we have decided to return error, we couldn't just print `_`. I mean if we write `_` in a normal mode it print `_` and in normal mode it will have another definition.

What are the reasons for choosing that decision?

Comment: The same goes for other active characters as well, like `$`, or `^`, or `&`, or `~`, ... are you okay with these?

Comment: for $ and ~ yes.

Comment: Then the answer is simple (like with all the others): `_` has special meaning and should be used with care outside of these special contexts and should be escaped outside of these contexts (see [Escape character in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34580/5764)).

Comment: ...as for "What [is] the reason for [making this] decision?" Well, that's a design decision that implies what follows as being a *subscript*.

Comment: For _ we can't say in normal mode we will print _, in math mode we give him another meaning. for $, ~, % we can't do that as it has already a function in normal mode.

Comment: If you're just interested in printing a `_` see [Underscores in words (text)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48632/5764).

Comment: You could also use the underscore package. But read its documentation if you don't want to run into problem with underscores in file names and label etc.

Comment: It doesn't matter too much but I don't see why this has been closed as duplicate (and have voted to reopen) the other question is about how to get a text underscore which this question does not ask, it is a question about a design decision in the language (so admittedly not really answerable except by Knuth who could say what was in his mind at the time)

Comment: @Werner No I'm not interesting in printing _ (I know how to do that but thanks for the link I have learned others things). Like David Carlisle said in his comment my question is about design decision. I though that there were reasons for choosing that decision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a tex primitive behaviour not something defined in LaTeX. It is consistent with most other primitive math mode syntax, that it generates an error in text mode. `\alpha` for example.

Comment: Is Knuth the only who developed TeX?

Comment: @user230137 together with some help with specific parts from his students, yes.