# Is it possible to write the '%' symbol in text in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

I'm a beginner trying to use LaTeX.
I tried to write a sentence which includes the %-symbol using \text{}, but the function that the %-symbol has in LaTeX seems to block me from using it in a normal text sentence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\text{I can't use the %-symbol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have to type `\%` (backslash percent) to get a percent sign.

Comment: See also [Escape character in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34586/110998).

Comment: @Werner, are you sure this is a duplicate of the link of you've posted? It seems to me that is not the case. This post asks about typing special characters of Latex within a text.

Comment: There is no need for `\text{}`. You are already in the text mode.

Comment: @CroCo: Yes. [I can find it on Detexify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x11tq.png) and it is listed in Table 1 of [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). And the use-case would be no different if you *didn't* use `\text`.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Very simple, use `\` before the `%`:

```
\text{I can't use the \%-symbol}
```

Comment: I don't know why those commands are used, it's just a sort of template i'm using.

Comment: luuk, it what are you using latex for? i use it mainly for journal / article or beamer. and you really never have to use '/text'. let me know if i can help on anything