# ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \abx@list@location

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing, biber

I am trying to migrate my document from Bibtex to Biblatex (biber), but after the change I cannot compile my document anymore. In this mini file I am trying to find my bug.
What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate the help!!

(Background: The reason I am switching to biber is that I want to divide my literature into several groups. And I was told that biber would be the easiest option.)

TLDR: I cannot compile my code and I get the following error message (in TEXmaker):

```
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 34.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \abx@list@location.
<to be read again>
1
l.35 ...l durch die Medien geht \cite{Brown.2017}
und auch der Beruf des gew...
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

My bibfile:

```
@online{Brown.2017,
 author = {Brown, Meta S.},
 editor = {Forbes},
 year = {2017},
 title = {{Read This Before You Pay For That Masters In Data Science Program}},
 url = {\url{https://www.forbes.com/sites/metabrown/2017/10/31/read-this-before-you-pay-for-that-masters-in-data-science-program/#1a20e13f78b2}},
 urldate = {2018-10-19},
 origdate = {2017-10-31},
 abstract = {},
 location = {\url{https://www.forbes.com/sites/metabrown/2017/10/31/read-this-before-you-pay-for-that-masters-in-data-science-program/#1a20e13f78b2}},
 note = {Forbes. Zuletzt gepr{\"u}ft am 19.10.2018.}
}
```

My texfile:

```
    \documentclass[
    pdftex,
    oneside,            
    12pt,               
    parskip=half,       
    headheight = 14pt,
    headsepline,        
    footsepline,        
    footheight = 16pt,
    abstracton,     
    DIV=calc,       
    BCOR=8mm,
    headinclude=false,
    footinclude=false,
    listof=totoc,
    toc=bibliography,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,  
bibwarn=true,
bibencoding=utf8,
sortlocale=nyt,
citestyle=authoryear,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{BiblatexLiteratur.bib}



\begin{document}
Dadurch, dass Data Science im Moment viel durch die Medien geht \cite{Brown.2017} und auch der Beruf des gewählt \cite{Glassdoor.2018}.
\clearpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should usually not be necessary to pass `pdftex` as package option (or global class option), it can actually be detrimental if you happen to use a different engine than pdfTeX, so I suggest you drop that option. `bibwarn=true,` is already the default and need not be given as option. `bibencoding=utf8,` would be detected automatically with your settings and is thus also not needed. `citestyle=authoryear,` without `bibstyle=authoryear,` (which could be combined to `style=authoryear,`) is also a bit unusual. (With `style=authoryear`, `sortlocale=nyt,` would be the default.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the URL, specifically the special character `#`, in the `location` field. `#` is very special for LaTeX (see [Escape character in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34580/35864) for a list of other characters with special meanings) and causes problems even with `\url` if the `\url` command is an argument of another command – and this happens to be the case in the `.bbl` file.

Since `location` is not the semantically correct field to give the URL of an entry anyway, you should just delete that field. `location` (and its BibTeX alias `address`) is meant to hold the (physical) place of publication of the work (usually that is the place where the `publisher`, `organization` or `institution` resides).

The URL of a work should be given in the `url` field. (Special URIs like DOIs may have dedicated fields: `doi`, `eprint`) In the `url` field special characters like `#` are allowed and do not cause an error. It is also not necessary to escape the URL with `\url` there.

Your entry could look like in the following MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{Brown.2017,
  author  = {Brown, Meta S.},
  editor  = {Forbes},% or maybe even better: organization = {Forbes},
  year    = {2017},
  title   = {Read This Before You Pay For That Masters In Data Science Program},
  url     = {https://www.forbes.com/sites/metabrown/2017/10/31/read-this-before-you-pay-for-that-masters-in-data-science-program/},
  urldate = {2018-10-19},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Brown.2017}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Brown, Meta S. (2017). Read This Before You Pay For That Masters In Data Science Program. Ed. by Forbes. url: https://www.forbes.com/sites/metabrown/2017/10/31/read-this-before-you-pay-for-that-masters-in-data-science-program/ (visited on 19/10/2018).]

I omitted the `#1a20e13f78b2` from the URL, because the link worked fine without the `#` bit as well (as one should be able to expect: the `#` usually signifies an anchor *on* the page, but it didn't take me anywhere else than the top of the page).

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly and now I can omit my dirty work-arounds to display the URL and the visited date.

Comment: @feeder Glad I could help. Happy TeXing!