# Unable to add references file in main file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm stuck on writing references in my main text. Can anybody please help out with the code? If I go to PDF for the same, I'm unable to get anything out of it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
\bibliography{references} 

\begin{document}

Random citation \autocite[1]{1} embedded in text. This is for my second reference \autocite[2]{2}. This one for third \autocite[3]{3}.

\newpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is my reference.bib file.

```
@article{1,
author = {Antúlio N. Bomfim & Francis X. Diebold},
title = {Bounded Rationality and Strategic Complementarity in a Macroeconomic Model: Policy Effects, Persistence and Multipliers},
journaltitle = {The Economic Journal, Volume 107, Issue 444, 1 September 1997, Pages 1358–1374},
date = {27 January 2012},
}

@article{2,
author = {Saang Joon Baak},
title = {Tests for bounded rationality with a linear dynamic model distorted by heterogeneous expectations},
journaltitle = {Journal of Economic Dynamics & Control 23 (1999) 1517}1543},
date = {20 November 1998},
}

@article{3,
author = {Luca Anderlini & David Canning},
title = {Structural Stability Implies Robustness to Bounded Rationality},
journaltitle = {Journal of Economic Theory 101, 395422 (2001)},
date = {17 August 2001},
}
```

I'm attaching a screenshot for the same. 
[image: LaTeX]

Comment: There is one fatal BibTeX-error in the `.bib` file. The `journaltitle` of `2` has `journaltitle = {Journal of Economic Dynamics \& Control 23 (1999) 1517}1543},`, i.e. the curly braces are closed twice. You probably want `journaltitle = {Journal of Economic Dynamics & Control 23 (1999) 1517–1543},` in line with `1`. It also contains another issue: Multiple names *must* be separated with `and` not with a `&`. The `&` will lead to a LaTeX error. The `&` in `Journal of Economic Dynamics & Control` must be escaped to `Journal of Economic Dynamics \& Control`. ...

Comment: After running LaTeX, did you run

Comment: ... The correct format for dates in the `date` field is `YYYY-MM-DD` (regardless of the expected output): So `date = {27 January 2012},` should be `date = {2012-01-27},`. Lastly, the `journaltile` field should only contain the journal title. Volume and issue number, date and page numbers should be given in the appropriate fields.

Comment: You should also consider using more informative names for your entries than just `1`, `2` and `3`. Those keys do not appear in the bibliography and citations and are purely internal. There is no correspondence with sorting or the numbering of footnotes.

Comment: @moewe I did all of that, thanks a lot. But still unable to run it. If I again go to the PDF of the untitled.tex document, unable to fetch anything. Can anyone please help?

Comment: @Mico Can you provide it's coding so that I can get my result?

Comment: Have not check tested moewe s comments but expect they should work when you select Correct compile pldlatex+Bib... option from tools not just run defauilt quick build what are any residual errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with the shown `.bib` file. Some of them are fatal.

- The `journaltitle` of `2` has two closing curly braces. It reads

  ```
  journaltitle = {Journal of Economic Dynamics & Control 23 (1999) 1517}1543},
  ```

  but was probably intended to be (this is still not correct, see the next point)

  ```
  journaltitle = {Journal of Economic Dynamics & Control 23 (1999) 1517-1543},
  ```

  This error is fatal and will stop BibTeX from processing your file.
- The `journaltitle` of `2` contains an unescaped `&` sign. `&` is special for LaTeX and must be escaped to `\&` if you want to typeset it. See [Escape character in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34580/35864).

  ```
  journaltitle = {Journal of Economic Dynamics \& Control 23 (1999) 1517-1543},
  ```

  This error is not fatal for BibTeX, but when the data comes to LaTeX it will cause a fatal error.
- Multiple names must be separated with `and` regardless of the desired output. `&` is incorrect here. [How to properly write multiple authors in bibtex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864). So

  ```
  author = {Antúlio N. Bomfim & Francis X. Diebold},
  ```

  is incorrect. You'd need

  ```
  author = {Antúlio N. Bomfim and Francis X. Diebold},
  ```

  Similar to the last issue, this problem will not cause BibTeX to fail, but LaTeX will throw an error when it gets the data.
- `biblatex`'s date fields must be filled in the ISO 8601/EDTF format `YYYY-MM-DD` regardless of the expected output.

  ```
  date = {20 November 1998},
  ```

  is wrong, you need

  ```
  date = {1998-11-20},
  ```
- The `journaltitle` field should only contain the journal title. All other info like volume, issue number, pages and date should go into the respective fields.
- The *entry keys* should ideally be more informative and useful than just `1`, `2`, `3`. You could use more memorable identifiers such as the name of the authors, a year or important bits of the title. Note that normally the entry key is a purely internal identifier, it does not affect sorting, does not correspond to anything in the output and is generally independent of all `biblatex` features.

You need to compile your document with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX. See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). But if you use `biblatex` it is much better to use Biber instead of BibTeX. See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) as well as [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Please have a look at one of the many `biblatex` tutorials out there. [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) is a great starting point.

Since your files contained so many errors, you probably need to clear out all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) after you have fixed the errors before you can recompile.

Here is what I would do (note that I use Biber and compile with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX. If you want to use BibTeX change `backend=biber` to `backend=bibtex` and compile with BibTeX instead of Biber.)

**Note** The MWE uses `filecontents` to produce the contents of the `.bib` file. The document will overwrite an exiting `.bib` file with the same name. In your real-world document you would paste the contents of the `filecontents` environment for `\jobname.bib` into your `.bib` file and would not need `filecontents` at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bomfim,
  author       = {Antúlio N. Bomfim and Francis X. Diebold},
  title        = {Bounded Rationality and Strategic Complementarity
                  in a Macroeconomic Model: Policy Effects,
                  Persistence and Multipliers},
  journaltitle = {The Economic Journal},
  volume       = {107},
  number       = {444},
  pages        = {1358-1374},
  date         = {1997-09},
  eprint       = {2957740},
  eprinttype   = {jstor},
}
@article{baak,
  author       = {Saang Joon Baak},
  title        = {Tests for bounded rationality with a linear dynamic
                  model distorted by heterogeneous expectations},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Economic Dynamics \& Control},
  volume       = {23},
  number       = {9-10},
  pages        = {1517-1543},
  date         = {1999-09},
  doi          = {10.1016/S0165-1889(98)00082-7},
}
@article{anderlini,
  author       = {Luca Anderlini and David Canning},
  title        = {Structural Stability Implies Robustness to
                  Bounded Rationality},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Economic Theory},
  volume       = {101},
  number       = {2},
  pages        = {395-422},
  date         = {2001-12},
  doi          = {10.1006/jeth.2000.2784},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Random citation \autocite[1359]{bomfim} embedded in text.
This is for my second reference \autocite[1520-1522]{baak}.
This one for third \autocite[395]{anderlini}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Verbose citations and bibliography of the three example entries.]

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thanks a lot for such a detailed answer! Really appreciating your help.

Comment: I've just one followup question, in references, I'm getting only the first one as  a reference and not the rest of the two? Is there any specific problem with that?

Comment: @Henam Sorry, I don't quite get what you mean. Can you please ask a new question explaining what you have so far, what you are doing, what you see and what you would like to see instead?

Comment: Okay sure, will do that! Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: I got what you're showing, was committing an error. Thanks