# impossible to locate Error ! Missing delimiter (. inserted)

Tags: errors

I can't find the error here

> ! Missing delimiter (.
>   inserted).

```
\sum_j \left{Q_j - \left[ \frac{d} {\text{d}t} \left(\frac{\partial T} {\partial \dot{q}_j} \right) - \frac{\partial T} {\partial q_j} \right] \right} \delta q_j = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\left\{` `\right\{` instead of `\left{` `\right{`

```
$\sum_j \left\{Q_j - \left[ \frac{d} {\text{d}t} \left(\frac{\partial T} {\partial \dot{q}_j} \right) - \frac{\partial T} {\partial q_j} \right] \right\} \delta q_j = 0$
```

Hope it works.

Comment: it works, but why can I use \left( and \left[ but not \left { ?

Comment: Refer the following link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex/34586#34586