# How to write \% separated in latex?

Tags: symbols

I have a link that contains %, but obviously writing it in this way it appears only "%". How can I write and visualize them both?
For example, I have:

```
\bibitem{} https://wxguys.ssec.wisc.edu/2016/07/11/high-winds/#:~:text=Since%20wind%20is%20air%20in,also%20cause%20it%20to%20move.
```

I need that after "Since" there is \ before all %.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want to print a URL that contains the % symbol? Could you provide an example of such a URL to illustrate the problem?

Comment: @JasperHabicht I have updated it

Comment: Do you write the `\bibitems` manually? Normally, if you use BibTeX, the URL should automatically be wrapped inside the `\url` macro, which allows the use of % without escaping. You can use the `\url` macro here as well, I assume. You would need to load the `url` package to be able to use it. WIthout more code and context, it is hard to tell what would be the best solution in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily change the catcode of "%"

```
\begingroup 
\catcode`\%=12
https://wxguys.ssec.wisc.edu/2016/07/11/high-winds/:~:text=Since%20wind%20is%20air%20in,also%20cause%20it%20to%20move.
\endgroup
```

[image]

Comment: [symbols - Escape character in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex) already cover how to typeset the symbol. In this case OP appears to want some biblatex thing