# How does one insert a backslash or a tilde (~) into LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

- How does one insert a "\" (backslash) into the text of a LaTeX document?
- And how does one insert a "~" (tilde)? (If you insert `\~`, it will give you a tilde as an accent over the following letter.)

I believe `\backslash` may be used in math formulae, but not into text itself. Lamport's, Kopka's, and Mittelbach's texts have said as much (but no more), and so left me hanging on how to get a backslash into regular text.

Comment: For the special case where a backslash or tilde must be written to an auxiliary file or shell escape see: [How can I provide a verbatim (unescaped) commandline for executing with \write18?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14186/24281#24281)

Comment: For future reference, [this](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is a great resource for finding out what to do to accomplish a given character.

Comment: For MathJax use simply `\sim`.

Comment: One of the bad ideas of mine, before I started using ˝\sim˝, was (don't use it): $\text{~}$

Comment: Special case of [symbols - Escape character in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex)

Comment: In-depth discussion about the tilde “~” here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312/42

Answer (score 1055, accepted):

#### TL;DR

`\textbackslash` produces a backslash in text-mode. The math-mode `$\sim$` and `\texttildelow` (from `textcomp` package) are options for a lower tilde *(while `\~{}` and `\textasciitilde` produce a raised tilde in text-mode)*

---

#### Long Answer:

The [*Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) is your friend. The correct link seems to keep changing, but if you have a complete TeX Live installation, the command `texdoc symbols-a4` will display your local copy.

`\textbackslash` and `\textasciitilde` are found in several places in the document, but the *LaTeX 2e ASCII Table* (Table 529 as of this writing) and the following discussion are a convenient resource for all ASCII characters. In particular, the discussion notes that `\~{}` and `\textasciitilde` produce a raised tilde, whilst the math-mode `$\sim$` and `\texttildelow` are options for a lower tilde; the latter is in the `textcomp` package, and looks best in fonts other than *Computer Modern*. If you are typesetting file names or urls, the document recommends the `url` package.

Remember to delimit TeX macros from surrounding text, e.g. `bar\textasciitilde{}foo`.

Comment: This is pretty awesome and helped me a lot. I just want to add that in case you use these in a text, do like so: `bar\textasciitilde{}foo`.

Comment: When Zotero exports a bibtex file, it replaces some tildes with `{\textasciitilde}`. When using biblatex (using the bibtex backend in texlive2007 [don't ask]), this causes an error (`Missing $ inserted`). The workaround is to use `{\textasciitilde{}}`.

Comment: There's also [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: And there is [write-math.com](http://write-math.com). I've just tried it: [Tilde](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/view/?raw_data_id=2548) and [backslash](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/view/?raw_data_id=2550). It works :-) (it's my bachelors thesis - currently still in progress)

Comment: This answer is misleading, `\textascitilde` will produce a tilde from the current font in font encodings that have tilde. It only produces the tilde accent over an empty base in the legacy OT1 encoding

Comment: whohoo it was so satisfying to push the votes from 999 to 1000, congrats!

Answer (score 329):

## Canonical answer

There’s now [an extensive discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312/42) with a [canonical answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377/42) on this website. Use the solution described there. tl;dr:

For a URL or file path, use [`url`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) (or [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)). Otherwise:

1. If you are using the standard [*Computer Modern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern) font, [`txfonts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/txfonts) or [`pxfonts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pxfonts): use this workaround:

   ```
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \newcommand{\textapprox}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\texttildelow}}
   ```

   … or use Latin Modern fonts instead (see next point).
2. If you are using a [PostScript/Type1 font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#Type_1) via a package such as [`mathptmx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx) or [`lm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lm): Set the font encoding to T1 (via [`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontenc)) and use `\textasciitilde`.
3. If you are using a TTF or OTF font via XeTeX or LuaTeX: Use `` \char`~ `` to insert a tilde.

## Obsolete answer, preserved for posterity

`textcomp`’s **`\texttildelow`** is actually quite a bad choice: it’s *too* low for most fonts.

A *much* better rendering can be achieved by the following, which tweaks the appearance of the (otherwise too wide) `$\sim$`:

```
{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\sim$}}
```

This was taken from the [Arbitrary LateX reference](http://latex.knobs-dials.com/) … the page also provides a good comparison sheet:

[image: Different tilde renderings]

When used in `\texttt`, I would add a `\mathtt` around the tilde, to make it fit the font better:

```
{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathtt{\sim}$}}
```

The difference is small but noticeable.

Comment: I'm trying to get a backslash in a monospaced font. ``\texttt{\textbackslash}`` is giving me the wrong glyph. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @nnyby: The best solution for that is to use the “raw” glyph, i.e. ``\texttt{\char`\\}``.

Comment: all of this: `{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\sim$}}`  just to type a proper `~`. And LaTeX is supposed to be allow you to focus on contents...

Comment: @Vivi: The point of (La)TeX is that you *can* focus on content by defining macros. You never need to (or should!) type the above – except once, in a macro definition. You *could* even define an active character so that `~` will actually insert a proper tilde. That said, you’re certainly right about this particular instance: not providing a 1:1 mapping to all Unicode characters (heck, not even ASCII) is a major weakness of LaTeX.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I love LaTeX (I am learning Emacs because of LaTeX, and I spent quite some time playing with the package TikZ)!! I just found it ironic in this instance...

Comment: This was a great solution. Thank you.  Though I would recommend putting it into its own new command like: `\newcommand{\mytilde}{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathtt{\sim}$}}` so you can simple write `\mytilde`.

Comment: I would say \sim is not good to use in text mode. we can get a vertically centered tilde by using `\raisebox{.4ex}{\hbox{\texttildelow}}` or `{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont\texttildelow}`. These two command can get better rendered tilde in text mode. At least provide a comparison between the rendered results of these command for reader to choose from.

Comment: @Hao That’s also a bad solution. There’s a canonical question/answer for this now: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312/42

Comment: To define `~` as an active character so that you can use it directly add the following to your preamble: ```\catcode`~ = 13```
```\def~{{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\sim$}}}```

Comment: @KonradRudolph could an "active character" be used to solve this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/592688/143861

Comment: @theonlygusti It could (see the immediately preceding comment), but `~` already *is* an active character with an altogether different meaning, it’s probably not a good idea to override that meaning since it’s fairly widely used.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think you missed the question link in my comment, probably the active character would have to be `!` with variable behaviour depending on what text is prefixed to it

Comment: @theonlygusti I didn’t miss the link, I just didn’t understand that you were seeking a solution to the issue in *that question*, because if so, why post it here? Where is the connection to this answer? At any rate, no, making `!` an active character is unlikely to solve your issue since you can’t generally inspect preceding characters inside a macro expansion, as far as I know (*if* this is possible at all it’s bound to be very inefficient in the general case). That said, I haven’t programmed in LaTeX in a looong time. I might misremember.

Comment: `{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\sim$}}` gave me the perfect result.

Comment: @vahid-dan Hm. That’s actually the obsolete answer. It really shouldn’t be used any more — it was purely a hacky workaround before the old, buggy fonts were fixed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph How can I get the same output using non-hacky standard methods? I tried several other methods and the tilde is either too high, too low, or too wide.

Comment: @vahid-dan Depending on your circumstances, one of the three initially described ways *should* work, and give the rendering of the tilde as intended by the authors of the typeface. The hack will give an imprecise approximation.

Answer (score 106):

You can also use the "plain TeX" method of indexing the actual ascii character in the current font:

```
\char`\\
\char`\~
```

I often use the former for writing macros that need the backslash in the typewriter font; `\textbackslash` will sometimes still use the roman font depending on the font setup. Of course, if you're using these a lot you should define your own macro for them:

```
\newcommand\SLASH{\char`\\}
```

Comment: rather ``\newcommand{\backslash}{\char`\\}``

Comment: Eh? The macro name can be whatever you like. The braces around it are optional. And `\backslash` is already defined as a math entity.

Comment: This is my preferred solution for backslash, as it suits the font of the surrounding environment (for example, you can use it in `\texttt`).

Comment: To any noobies out there, you'd call this by writing $\SLASH{thing you want to put a backslash in front of}$

Comment: @Greg — no need for the braces.

Comment: Understood, I'm new and enjoyed the verbosity, but I follow!

Comment: For backslash, I get different results running this in math mode versus out of math mode. In normal mode it outputs a double quote instead of a backslash. This is with a fresh install & a minimal tex file, so there must be something else I'm not doing.

Comment: don't try this in OT1.....

Comment: @jpaugh Since it seems to only work in math mode, I explicitly put it in math mode: `\newcommand\SLASH{$\char\`\\$}`

Answer (score 66):

I occurs to me that you might be trying to type URLs. In that case, the `url` package takes care of everything for you:

```
\usepackage{url}
...
\url{somewhere\home\~will}
```

For paths (i.e., local files), there is `\path`, working the same way as `\url`, just providing the correct links in case `hyperref` is loaded.

If you are loading `hyperref` there is no reason to load `url` as well.

Comment: Thank you Will, I was trying to typeset teletype backslash (thick one) in new command. I've found way how to solve it but using `url` package is much more elegant.

Comment: Unfortunately the produced output is not clickable anymore, neither in DVI nor PDF. Any way to make it clickable?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev — I don't know what you mean by clickable. Are you loading the hyperref package? You don't need to load `url` separately in that case.

Comment: @WillRobertson Thank you for clarifying, I have managed to make it clickable (so that clicking on it opens the page in a browser) by loading the `hyperref` package instead of the `url` package but still using `\url{...}` rather than `href{...}`

Answer (score 63):

Well if that isn't annoying:

```
 \textbackslash
 \texttt{\char`\~} or $\sim$
```

Comment: BMH or someone else: please edit if you have better answers for the tilde.

Comment: Don't use `\verb`, because it will break in fragile arguments. `\texttt{\char\`\~}` would be the better choice. (See my answer elsewhere on this page.)

Comment: @Will: Fixed that.

Answer (score 18):

Hmm; `\textbackslash` (mentioned by others) isn't in my reference book ([Kopka and Daly)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201398257).

At any rate, math mode provides `\sim`, `\backslash`, and `\setminus` (the latter two appear to look the same and differ only by spacing in math mode).

My LaTeX book – which, as you would expect, features the \ extensively – seems to use the `verbatim` environment.  For example, this code:

```
\begin{verbatim}
 \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\footnotetext{Small insects}
 \stepcounter{footnote}\footnoteext{Large mammals}
\end{verbatim}
```

Produces this text in the book:

```
 \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\footnotetext{Small insects}
 \stepcounter{footnote}\footnoteext{Large mammals}
```

The `\verb` command is similar, but the argument must be on one line only.  The first character after the b is the delimiter; for example:

```
\verb=\emph{stuff}=
```

will produce

```
\emph{stuff}
```

So you could presumably get your backslash by typing:

```
\verb=\=
```

You can also add a `*` – i.e. `\verb*` or `\begin{verbatim*}` – to make whitespace visible.

It is interesting to speculate how you would get an example of a `verbatim` environment into a document..
(using `\verb` to do the last line, I guess)

Comment: I guess the problem with using `\verb` is that it breaks inside macro arguments. You can't write `\section{\verb=~=}`, for example.

Comment: Kopka's LaTeX books are very old. Originally they were written for LaTeX 2.09 and the later editions are only less modified for LaTeX2e. So they are not the best description of LaTeX2e and at least not of packages available for LaTeX2e. `\textbackslash` for example has been described at [LaTeX2e for authors](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/usrguide) by the LaTeX team.

Comment: \textbackslash is on page 536 of the fourth edition of Kopka and Daly

Answer (score 9):

For the tilde, you can use empty curly brace pair. That puts the "over the letter" tilde over an "empty" letter, so it's placed upward.

```
My tilde\~{}here
```

Comment: I guess it depends what the OP is intending to do with the tilde. Sometimes a "naked" tilde is a little unobtrusive.

Answer (score 6):

From https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/tex/bibliographies.html

> "... tilde symbol (`~`), which without
>   special coding gets interpreted as a
>   blank space, and therefore needs to be
>   escaped by a backslash (`\~`) or
>   replaced by the math "twiddle" symbol
>   `$\sim$`. Fortunately, there is a
>   package, `url`, that provides a
>   painless way to typeset URL's. To use
>   this package available, add
>
> ```
> \usepackage{url}
> ```
>
> near the beginning of the document,
>   and enclose any web and email
>   addresses in the document in
>   `\url{...}`:
>
> ```
> \url{http://www.math.drofnats.edu/~gauss}
> \url{gauss@math.drofnats.edu}
> ```
>
> ..."

I hope this could help you in typewriting a regular tilde character.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I learned more actually changing the `catcode`s myself :)

```
\begingroup
  \catcode `~=11
  \gdef\mytilde{~}
  \catcode `\|=0
  \catcode `\\=11
  |gdef|mybs{\}
|endgroup
```

and then something like

```
This is a tilde: \mytilde
This is a backslash: \mybs
```

Comment: `\def\mybs{\char092}` does the same for the backslash

Comment: @Herbert: True, but more cryptic ...

Comment: ok, then we use `\string\ ` for non cryptic ...

Answer (score 2):

$\sim$ works for me in **Plain TeX**.

Eg. `~70` can be rendered as

```
$\sim$70
```