# How to express ~ (tilde)

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex)

How do I express `~` in LaTeX. I have tried `\~` but it doesn't work. Is there a specific syntax for it and is there a reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: `\textasciitilde` or `$\sim$`, depending on your preference. You could also use `\verb!~!`, but this will typeset it using `\ttfamily`.

Comment: ...as a side note, the reason why it doesn't work is because `\~` is a command that provides a tilde accent, and therefore requires an argument: `\~{a}` or `\~o`. On the other hand, using only `~` is what is called an unbreakable space or "tie" in LaTeX.