# How to use special symbols in LaTeX, such as @, ~

Tags: symbols, tilde

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex)

I wonder how I can typeset in LaTeX this text:
@Data.test~

I mean, I want to have in the end "To display the data we use token @Data.test~."
I searched symbols documentation, but only found \textasciitilde, which was not what I wanted.
And no command for using @ in the text except \MVAt, but it is displayed in bold.

Thank you!

Comment: Not a direct answer but an idea : `\makeatletter @\makeatother\relax Data.test\textasciitilde`

Comment: @percusse You can use `@` directly: contrary to what people tend to think, it is _not_ 'special' in document-level material.

Comment: @percusse You don't need `\makeatletter` to *print* a @. Use simply the symbol itself. `\makeatletter` is only needed when you want @ in a command name.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, but I remember breaking down some macro (can't remember what it was) with it though. Maybe it was because of something else.

Comment: Aha, OK, @ works. But \textasciitilde puts tilde too high, not in the middle of the line. It looks like the tilde is above some empty character.

Comment: @Oleksandr see the link I've given in the first comment.

Comment: for tilde, use $\sim$

Comment: Also, for better looking @, you do `\usepackage{marvosym}` and `\MVAt`. Found using http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: @Vivi this depends on the font. With newtxtext and newtxmath the best result is `@Data.test\textasciitilde` - `$\sim$` and `MVAt` look very ugly in that context.

Comment: @joseph, ulrike: "@" used to have a special meaning in amstex (the plain tex predecessor of amslatex), and because of that there's actually a faq question about typing "@".  the answer was slightly archaic in the first release of the faq (1994) but it's still there.  perhaps oleksandr has been using tex a looooong time...

Answer (score -1):

Since this is probably either a command in some programming language or a file name, I think it makes more sense semantically to switch to a monospace font to typeset it.

With this modification, you can achieve the result you want with `\verb|@Data.test~|`. Or you can use the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package and then `\lstinline{@Data.test~}`.