# How do I draw a tilde in math mode?

Tags: tilde

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex)

I have tried using `\text{\~{}}` to draw a tilde in math mode. However, this only produces a superscript tilde.

I have looked around at many pages such as this one:
http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols

and surprisingly, I can't find where to draw a tilde in math mode (not under or above a character - just a single tilde character). If I just use `~`, then nothing appears.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\backsim\ \sim\ \thicksim$
\end{document}
```

[image: Image showing possible tildes in LaTeX]

Comment: What does "sim" stands for? This is a short for what?

Comment: I believe "sim" is short for similar. This symbol is often used to relate similar things, such as in linear algebra where ~ means two matrices are row-equivalent (which is a similarity between those matrices).

Comment: @definecindyconst Do you know if the `\backsim` has a seperate meaning, or if it's just artistic choice?

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen First I just want to clarify that my previous comment is just an educated guess -- I don't have any particular knowledge as to why Latex commands are named as they are. However, many different areas of maths use a tilde to denote that two things are "similar" where "similar" tends to mean different things in different areas. I have never personally seen anyone use a mirrored tilde specifically in mathematics, and if I saw it in literature without further explanation I would assume it to have the same meaning as a regular tilde given how similar they look.

Comment: @definecindyconst Yeah, my guess would be the same, I was just curious, I've also never seen the `\backsim` symbol used, and my search engine efforts to learn its possible meaning have sadly been fruitless. for now I'll assume that it is a purely artistic choice. Hopefully that won't end up biting me 8-)

Answer (score 23):

Is `\sim`  an option for you? It looks like a tilde.