# How do I print '~' in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I draw a tilde in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75237/how-do-i-draw-a-tilde-in-math-mode)

I need to print `$ X_i~N(\mu,\sigma)$` but `~` and `\~` don't work in math mode in LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! You're looking for `\sim`, probably.

Comment: Try drawing it in [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: Karina, have a look at the question linked by Scott and let us know if it doesn't answer your question. If it does, your question will be closed to keep the place tidy.

Answer (score 4):

`texdoc comprehensive` is your friend

```
$X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$
```