# Can we have x with tilde on top?

Tags: symbols, tilde

Basically, I want to have a X with `tilde` ontop of X.

[image]

I tried to follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\backsim\ \sim\ \thicksim$
\end{document}
```

But this only output `tilde`

from [How to draw a tilde in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75237/how-do-i-draw-a-tilde-in-math-mode)

Comment: What about $\tilde{x}$?

Comment: You can try also widetilde (more greater than tilde) `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\widetilde{x}$
\end{document}`

Comment: Combinations of letters and diacritics are not generally provided as single symbols; in fact, I can't think of a single one.  The mechanism to be used is shown in the comment by @WillieWong.

Answer (score 3):

`$\tilde{x}$`

why is it  so problematic?

Comment: thanks. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524157/how-to-have-vector-length-with-tilde-x