# How to have vector length with tilde X?

Tags: symbols

Following the question in [Can we have x with tilde on top?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524154/can-we-have-x-with-tilde-on-top)

Basically, i want to have vector lenght like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\| \tilde{x} \|  $   

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

But how to have another tilde at the bottom of X?

Comment: maybe the [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) Table252:undertilde helps. Found it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: @TivV Thanks. I tried `$\| \undertilde{\widetilde{x}} \|$`, `$\| \undertilde\widetilde{x} \|$`. Even `$\undertilde{x}$` also not working.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23093/172164

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two variants with  the `accents` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

$ \| \underaccent{\tilde}{\tilde{x}} \| \qquad\| \undertilde{\widetilde{x}} \| $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Another link questions https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524175/how-to-force-a-space-in-tilde-vector

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{undertilde}

\begin{document}
$\| \utilde{\tilde{x}} \|$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Yours MWE above, when I used in overleaf, it generate error, saying "LaTex Error: File `undertilde.sty` not found. Did i make mistake?

Comment: Can I suggest you try the second part of the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23096/172164