# How to force a space in tilde vector?

Tags: spacing, symbols

Following the question in [How to use tilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524157/how-to-have-vector-length-with-tilde-x/524162#524162)

I want to have space between `tilde`.
i tried used `\space` but not effect.

for example:

```
$\hat{\undertilde{\widetilde{x}}}$ $=$ $\sqrt{0^2, \space\widetilde{x_1}^2, \space\widetilde{x_2}, ..., 1}$

$\hat{\undertilde{\widetilde{x}}}$ $=$ $\sqrt{0^2,\space\widetilde{x_1}^2,\space\widetilde{x_2}^2, ..., 1}$
```

[image]

Full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

% $ \| \underaccent{\tilde}{\tilde{x}} \| $

% This is my $\|\undertilde{\widetilde{x}}\|$

$\hat{\undertilde{\widetilde{x}}}$ $=$ $\sqrt{0^2, \space\widetilde{x_1}^2, \space\widetilde{x_2}, ..., 1}$

$\hat{\undertilde{\widetilde{x}}}$ $=$ $\sqrt{0^2,\space\widetilde{x_1}^2,\space\widetilde{x_2}^2, ..., 1}$


\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\,` or `\;` instead of `\space` (and `\dots` instead of `...`).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat. It really works well. Thanks, brillant!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

    % $ \| \underaccent{\tilde}{\tilde{x}} \| $

    % This is my $\|\undertilde{\widetilde{x}}\|$

    $\hat{\undertilde{\widetilde{x}}}$ $=$ $\sqrt{0^2, \,\widetilde{x_1}^2, \,\widetilde{x_2}, \cdots, 1}$

    $\hat{\undertilde{\widetilde{x}}}$ $=$ $\sqrt{0^2,\,\widetilde{x_1}^2,\,\widetilde{x_2}^2, \cdots, 1}$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be good if your answer indicated that you changed `\space` to `\,`, as a comment suggested.  And ams provides `\dotsc`, on the off chance someone decides that dots between commas should be `\ldots`.