# How do I insert a backslash inside a mathematical statement?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amssymb

I'm trying to write a set subtraction operation in an AMS formatted template.  In the end, what I want should look like A\B.  But I'm doing this in math-mode `$A\B$` and this gives me errors.  I've also tried using the `\diagdown` symbol, but it doesn't work either.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Remember that \ is TeX escape character, so TeX is seeing `\B` as a macro name (probably undefined). What about `$A\backslash B$`?

Comment: For your special Problem, @corentin already gave the answer below. For a more geneal answer, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9363/18674

Answer (score 160, accepted):

`\setminus` should be what you are after.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \smallsetminus

\begin{document}
\[ \mbox{setminus: } A \setminus B,\quad \mbox{smallsetminus: } A \smallsetminus B, \quad \mbox{backslash: } A \backslash B\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you can find more information here on [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol). In particular, you have the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbols](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and the website [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). There is also [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex) which was mentioned earlier in a comment

Comment: You can include also `$\backslash$`, which produces a different spacing, for comparison.

Comment: @JLDiaz Thanks for your comment, you are right, I will update my post.

Comment: there is also `\smallsetminus`, available with `\usepackage{amssymb}`, for those who prefer a smaller symbol (with the same meaning).

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks! :)