# How to make "\" in latex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How to make '\' in latex if '\' has to be used in set theory equations?
I have to use it in the following format

```
$\forall X \in 2^\Omega-{\emptyset} $
```

Here instead of '-' sign i want to use '\'. Is there a way about it?

Comment: `\setminus` is perhaps what you're looking for.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86269/how-do-i-insert-a-backslash-inside-a-mathematical-statement?lq=1