# Beamer equation error

Tags: beamer, equations

I am having some problems with my recent Beamer presentation, namely with equations.

I would like to typeset the phrase `$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$` in a typewriter font inside an equation, to show the syntax of LaTeX equations for a presentation that I am making.

However, I am getting vague errors when I compile the following MWE using XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{amsmath, amstext}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame}
    \begin{equation*}
      \mathtt{\$\$\\sum\_\{i=1\}\;\widehat{}\;\{n\}i=\\frac\{n(n+1)\}\{2\}\$\$}
    \end{equation*}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.3 ...idehat{}\;\{n\}i=\\frac\{n(n+1)\}\{2\}\$\$}

?
```

I also tried the verbatim environment, which works when replacing `\mathtt{...}` with `\verb|$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$|`, but fails when I attempt to animate it:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{amsmath, amstext}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame}
    \onslide<+->{
    \begin{equation*}
      \verb|$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$|
    \end{equation*}}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.5     \end{equation*}}

?
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: unrelated to the problem, but if you want to show the latex syntax of equations, don't show it with `$$...$$` ([Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503))

Comment: I am using `$$...$$`, because the presentation is about Jekyll-based website where the equations are rendered using KaTeX, and the setup I am using requires this syntax.

Comment: OK, that make sense. Back to the question: there is one point which I don't understand: why do you want to put this inside an unnumbered equations? Why not put it in some verbatim or listings environment instead?

Comment: You are right, I should not have made the equation unnumbered. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: ``\\`` does not produce a backslash.

Comment: I did not know that, that is likely the cause of the first error. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86269/how-do-i-insert-a-backslash-inside-a-mathematical-statement) explains how to typeset the backslash correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part of my question can be solved by removing the compound brackets after `\onslide<+->`:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{amsmath, amstext}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame}
    \onslide<+->
    \begin{equation*}
      \verb|$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$|
    \end{equation*}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```