# How to write "\" the set difference symbol without LaTeX getting confused?

Tags: symbols

I am trying to use the "\" symbol in my text for set difference but LaTeX gets confused and will not read it. How can I make it work?

Comment: Try `\setminus`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86269/35864