# How can I write tilde ~ in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)
>   [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex)

`~` makes symbols after them 'phantoms'. I want just to write '~' in math mode and `\~` doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

(I want to write 'x is asymptotically normal distributed')

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Are you perhaps looking for `\sim`?

Comment: Also related answer for different choices http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex

Comment: @percusse That question is more oriented towards getting a tilde in text mode.

Comment: @egreg oh sorry, I didn't parse the text while reading :)

Comment: Scratch that close vote of mine, sorry. I made the question a little more distinct from the other one my focusing on math mode.

Comment: The other famous tilde question could be made a bit more general and canonical by changing it to mean both text and math mode. Answers deal already with it in math mode. And the top answer could easily edited to reflect also math mode. I think this would be better than making near-duplicates distinct, so I think the dupe vote of @doncherry would be good.

Comment: You can write as a text mode character, this way: `$2014\text{\~}2015$`. But if you want it as a mathematical symbol you can use `\sim`.

Answer (score 136):

There are various ways to do it.

**Mathmode**

```
\sim
```

Using package `amssymb`

```
\thicksim
```

**Textmode**

```
\textasciitilde
```

You can always check [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)

Comment: Using `\sim` would appear to be the mathematically most correct way, since it produces TILDE OPERATOR (which is vertically positioned at operator level) as opposite to the Ascii TILDE (typically positioned higher).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: You are right. That's why I choose to mention it first. But I think that one has to have alternatives that best suit his/her needs!

Comment: If you don't want the space after the tilde, you can wrap it with curly braces. For example: ``${\sim} 10$``

Comment: @DanHickstein Fantastic tip. Exactly what most of us will need! (And it is not obvious...)