# How do I get a literal ~ in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde (~) into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex)
>   [How can I write tilde ~ in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86377/how-can-i-write-tilde-in-math-mode)

When I write $~$, I get a space. When I write $\~$, I get an error.

I am trying to write ~ to represent the equinumerous relation.

Comment: See e.g. [How can I write tilde ~ in math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86377) and its duplicates.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why I didn't find that when I was adding the question.