# How do you get a lower or higher tilde/~?

Tags: symbols

I want to presents hours and say from hour x to hour y by using sample '~'.
Please guide me how I can present the symbol "~"?

---

In contrast to [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde (~) into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex), I'm particularly interested in controlling the vertical placement of the `~`.

Comment: how about [how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex)

Comment: If the link given by cmhughes helped, we would close the question as a duplicate, for a clean and structured site.

Comment: @cmhughes, I used it it gaves the result ut the problem is that ~ is not in the level of line it is a litle bit higher than line.

Comment: could you provide a complete MWE that illustrates the problem? :)

Comment: Many people use `$x \sim y$`.

Comment: Please try the several methods in cmhughes link, there are variations in vertical position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In comments you indicated that it is the height of the `~` that is your concern, perhaps one of these does what you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

a\textasciitilde b\raisebox{-1ex}{\textasciitilde}c\raisebox{-1.2ex}{\textasciitilde}d\raisebox{-2ex}{\textasciitilde}e

\end{document}
```

Comment: I’m assuming this question will be closed; we should then merge it into the other question since this answer would be a great addition to it!

Comment: @doncherry Not sure it should be closed, if the title were instead "how do you make a low tilde" it would stand on its own. Despite the title I think the problem is more to do with raising/lowering than with `~`.

Comment: @doncherry: As the answer stands now, i.e. with a direct reference to the comments on this question, it's not suitable for merging by a moderator.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It's not just the question title. The body clearly just talks about how to inserting the tilde, which makes it a 100% duplicate. It needs to be rephrased to include the shifting requirement. Then it would make a good follow-up question.