# what is the the latex code for a wave line above a word?

Tags: symbols

I wish to write a wave line above the "ch" as described in the following picture, how should I do this?

[image]

Comment: See [How does one insert a backslash (``\``) or a tilde (`~`) into LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9363/5764)

Comment: `\tilde{ch}` or `\widetilde{ch}`?

Comment: `$\tilde{\text{ch}}$` (with the inclusion of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)).