# Trouble inserting "~" (not equivalent to \sim}

Tags: symbols, urls

I need to include a url in my document, which includes this symbol: `~`
Simply entering the url generates a space rather than the symbol, and replacing the symbol with `$\sim$` is not equivalent, the url no longer works if copied and pasted into a browser. Is there a way to generate the exact symbol? The full url I want to use is `http://www.its.caltech.edu/∼ph76a/pdh.pdf`.
Working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in]{geometry}              % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
http://www.its.caltech.edu/~ph76a/pdh.pdf
\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9369/15925

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already loading `url` package. Hence use `\url{<url address>}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\url{http://www.its.caltech.edu/~ph76a/pdh.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to make it a clickable link, use `hyperref`. The `url` package is loaded by `hyperref` itself.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{http://www.its.caltech.edu/~ph76a/pdh.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a slightly lowered tilde, pass the option `lowtilde` to `url` package. i.e.,

```
\usepackage[lowtilde]{url}
```

if using `url` package and

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{lowtilde}{url}
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
..
..
```

for `hyperref`.

The font style can be set by the `\urlstyle` command. From `url`  ([documentation](http://www.texdoc.net)):

> You can switch the style of printing using “\urlstyle{xx}”, where “xx”
>   can be any defined style. The pre-defined styles are “tt”, “rm”, “sf”
>   and “same” which all allow the same linebreaks but use different fonts
>   — the first three select a specific font and the “same” style uses the
>   current text font. You can define your own styles with different fonts
>   and/or line-breaking by following the explanations below. The “\url”
>   command follows whatever the currently-set style dictates.

Hence `\urlstyle{tt}` should give you the above style throughout.

Comment: Thanks very much - this has solved my problem, do you know of a way to keep the same formatting as the rest of my document? I'd prefer that if possible.

Comment: @Jennifer Use `\urlstyle{same}` to get the current text font.