# How to write character \

Tags: symbols, characters

I would like to write the character "\" in Latex but since it is a keyword I am struggling in doing so. Is there a way to write it somehow?

Comment: try `$\backslash$` or `\textbackslash`

Comment: see also: [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde (~) into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9363/123129)