# How can I generate the ~ symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, makeindex

Please help, I using TeXworks.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @VladyslavSemenyuk Can you give some context where you want to use this symbol? For example if it is part of an url, I suggest the `url` or `hyperref` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The code is `$\sim$`. Or `Alt+126` in ASCII character.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use it for e.g. values with units then it might be useful to use the `siunitx` package. You could then write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\SI{\sim 10}{\meter}

\end{document}
```

Note: removed '\approx' from earlier version of this answer since it doesn't give the desired symbol.

Comment: Awesome that you're making answers! Just a few pointers:
What do you mean by using the `\approx` command? It gives a symbol like this: `≈`, not this :`~`. Furthermore, try to be precise: that is the OP didn't mention units at all. Also: since it is already a suggested answer in the comments, you should at least acknowledge that too. - Again: it's great that you're trying to help, and that's only what I'm trying to do to!

Comment: No,`\approx` produces two superimposed tilde characters and not just one

Comment: You're right about the '\approx' command. Not sure what you mean with the comments though. I didn't see anything like that, maybe it was added while I was typing my answer. Anyway, thank you for the pointers.

Comment: @user169883 for your interlocutor to receive a notification that you have replied, it is necessary that his nickname is preceded by the `at` sign (as I just did on yours) ,  see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work