# How to type "~", the curly symbol used for "Home" in Linux, in latex?

Tags: symbols

I'm sorry if this is duplicate; I couldn't find it.

Comment: Try `\texttilde` or `\textasciitilde`

Comment: Also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1