# How can I expand a word? A command without a backslash?

Tags: macros

In my source code I would like `Snap!` to be automatically replaced with `Snap\textit{!}`

```
\newcommand{Snap!}{Snap\textit{!}}
```

Errors with "missing number, treating as zero"

Comment: With standard latex you cannot, this is probably a better job for the search-and-replace in your editor.

Comment: What's the problem with `\newcommand{\Snap}{Snap\textit{!}}`? What is the reason you want to get rid of the backslash?

Comment: @HenriMenke I wanted to write a "normal" paragraph in source, so the source was succinct and readable, and the output had the correct stylisation applied. So it wasn't preferred in the first place, but in the end I did resort to trying `\Snap` too, but that deletes spaces directly after itself.

Comment: @theonlygusti More "readable" source is always to wrong reason. If you want that, use Markdown and convert to LaTeX. Then you can also do things like in your question using [Pandoc Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html).

Comment: `\Snap\ ` puts the space back, there are several answers on this site about that.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with a comment that this is best handled in an editor, rather than in LaTeX.  But in the spirit of providing a LaTeX answer...

**Pure `listofitems` version**

Here, a macro `\snap` will examine its argument and do the replacement of `Snap!` with `Snap\textit{!}`.  However, unlike the `tokcycle` approach shown below, this version will not find `Snap!` occurrences inside of arguments, for example, `\textbf{blah Snap! blah}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle,listofitems,xcolor}
\setsepchar{Snap!}
\newcommand\snap[1]{%
  \readlist\mysnaps{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\mysnaps[]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt=1\else Snap\textit{!}\fi
    \z
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\snap{%
There is Snap! and other Snap  and snappy *Snap!* words!
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**`tokcycle` version**

If you can live with `!` being considered a "letter" (catcode-11), then there is this `tokcycle` environment `\snap...\endsnap` that will find exact instances of `Snap!` and replace the `!` as italic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle,listofitems,xcolor}
\catcode`!=11
\setsepchar{Snap!}
\newcommand\testdict{%
  \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\currentword}\relax\else
    {\ignoreemptyitems
      \greadlist\dictcompA{\currentword}}%
    \readlist\dictcompB{\currentword}%
    \ifnum\listlen\dictcompA[]=0\relax
      \addcytoks[1]{\autohighlightStyleA}%
      \addcytoks[1]{\expandafter{\currentword}}
    \else
      \ifnum\listlen\dictcompB[]>1\relax
        \addcytoks[1]{\autohighlightStyleB}%
        \addcytoks[1]{\expandafter{\currentword}}
      \else
        \addcytoks[1]{\currentword}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \gdef\currentword{}%
}
\makeatletter
\xtokcycleenvironment\snap
{\tctestifcatnx A##1{\g@addto@macro\currentword{##1}}
  {\testdict\addcytoks{##1}}}
{\testdict\groupedcytoks{\processtoks{##1}\testdict}}
{\g@addto@macro\currentword{##1}}
{\testdict\addcytoks{##1}}
{\stripgroupingtrue\def\currentword{}}
{}
\makeatother
\newcommand\autohighlightStyleA{\snapit}
\newcommand\autohighlightStyleB{\snapit}
\newcommand\snapit[1]{Snap\textit{!}}
\begin{document}
\snap

There is Snap! and other Snap  and snappy *Snap!* words!

\endsnap
\end{document}
```

[image]