# How to insert a vertically centered tilde into a URL?

Tags: symbols, urls, tilde, textcomp

I need to insert a vertically centered tilde into a URL in text mode (not inside the `\url` or `\href` commands). I've tried the solution proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex/9372#9372) but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Here is my code

```latex
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\newcommand{\textapprox}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\texttildelow}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{MWE}
https://foo.com/\textapprox{}user/
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \textapprox already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 ...extapprox}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\texttildelow}}
                                                  
?
```

Comment: well as the error says the command name already exist. So use another one or redefine the existing command (if you are sure that you don't need it).

Comment: Thank you! I feel so dumb. If you convert your comment into an answer I will be pleased to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says the command name already exist.

So use another one or redefine the existing command (if you are sure that you don't need it)