# Why does not Latex show the symbol tilde ~ (non-breaking space) before a citation or reference?

Tags: toptesi

When I try to put non-breaking space before citations, Latex does not show the symbol tilde (~) before the citations in rendered pdf.

Here is what I would like to see: According to xx (2013)~[refID]

```
According to xx (2013)~\cite{xx}
According to xx (2013)\nobreakspace\cite{xx}
```

However, what I get after using the codes above: According to xx (2013) [refID]

Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{key,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Title},
        publisher = {Publisher},
       }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

  According to xx\textasciitilde{}\cite{key}, ...

  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The MWE above produces the following output:
[image]

The problem is the space after the tilde. How can I remove that?

Comment: Maybe this is an answer to your question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9365/140456 or the other ones in the same question. Maybe the way to go is to change the way your citations are displayed, but without a (MWE)[https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography] it is impossible to help

Comment: `~` in LaTeX-syntax denotes a non-breaking-space: `a~b`  means to place `a<horizontal space>b` into the .pdf-output-file so that a linebreak will not occur between `a` and `b` but `a<horizontal space>b` will always be on the same line. If you want a tilde, use the control sequence `\textasciitilde`.

Comment: a non breaking space renders as a _space_ just as `&nbsp;` renders as a space in HTML. It would look very odd to have a `~` in the typeset result.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Using \textasciitilde leaves an unwanted space after: https://pasteboard.co/KaR2add.png

Comment: @LuisTurcio I have just edited my post for MWE. Thanks!

Comment: Are you **sure** you want a tilde printed there? Given that `~` means a non-breaking space in LaTeX, I'm wondering whether you've misinterpreted some instructions for how to write citations.

Comment: Not me but my professor wants to see that tilde printed there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your picture.
The picture generated at overleaf (via LuaLaTeX) is as follows:
[image]

Below is what I tried using my own TeX Live 2021:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{key,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Title},
        publisher = {Publisher},
       }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

According to xx\textasciitilde{ }\cite{key}, ...

According to xx\textasciitilde{}\cite{key}, ...

According to xx\textasciitilde\cite{key}, ...

According to xx\texttildelow\cite{key}, ...

According to xx\verb+~+\cite{key}, ...

According to xx$\sim$\cite{key}, ...

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually your last example is what I exactly want. However, when I try According to xx$\sim$\cite{key}, it leaves a space after the tilde.

Comment: Then, you might want to reinstall your TeX distribution or upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: I am using Overleaf. I guess it is already the latest version. I could not understand what the problem is.

Comment: I updated my answer, showing the picture generated at overleaf using your MWE.

Comment: It is weird, because I try the same, but doesn't produce the same output. I am using toptesi document class. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Your MWE uses article, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't use toptesi here, since it is a specific packet and many people here wouldn't have it.

Comment: I tried toptesi at overleaf, still no extra space.

Comment: I have just tried now in a different part of the text and it did not leave extra space. Maybe it is because of two-sided justification.

Comment: So, your example is not really an MWE. It's hard to help with a moving target.

Comment: You are right, I will edit this. I thought that it would be better to make it as simple as possible. Anyway, your answer helped me a lot. It should be related to the justification. Thank you!