# How to show ~(tilde) in footnote?

Tags: footnotes, tilde

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correctly typesetting a tilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312/correctly-typesetting-a-tilde)

I can show ~(tilde) in normal text, using text as follows,

```
\begin{quote}
\verb|~|
\end{quote}
```

But the problem is when I try to put this in footnote{}. Error will be thrown, how should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\~{}` for a tilde. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hi here\footnote{My character is ``\~{}'' and \texttt{I can also typset
it in this font: ``\~{}''}.}.
\end{document}
```

The group `{}` is quite important after the `\~`, otherwise LaTeX will think it's an accent to put on the next character.

Comment: So TeX puts the accent on nothing, right?

Answer (score 2):

How about `\textasciitilde` ? It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `\textasciitilde` command.

Answer (score 1):

\footnote{foo \~{} bar} works for me. If you want it in \verb style, but a \texttt around.