# Show tilde in footnote, with correct text formatting

Tags: footnotes, urls

I need to show a unix url in a footnote of my article document. Some of the posts such as [How to show ~(tilde) in footnote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14188/how-to-show-tilde-in-footnote)
have been very helpful, but I still have some questions.

I am using URL package. In my footnote I tried something like

```
   \url{http://www.site1.ext/~hello}
```

to show the unix URL, my questions are:

1- This changes the font of footnote. How can I ensure it is using the default footnote text similar to my other footnotes?

2- When I click on the address, it does not generate the correct url.

I have to adhere to some specific packages and guidelines so I may not be able to use certain packages. Any help is highly appreciated to guide me resolve this with simplest solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\urlstyle{}` to change the font. For example `\urlstyle{rm}` to use the default serif font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{rm}
\begin{document}
  This is a sentence\footnote{This is a footnote with a \url{http://www.somewhere.com/~spindles/}.}
\end{document}
```

[image: serif url]

If you want clickable links, you need to use `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{rm}
\begin{document}
  This is a sentence\footnote{This is a footnote with a \href{http://www.somewhere.com/~spindles/}{\url{http://www.somewhere.com/~spindles/}}.}
\end{document}
```

[image: clickable url with tilde]

Comment: Thanks @cfr for the answer. Is there a way to change the font for URL locally and not globally?

Comment: Put the style change inside the footnote before `\url{}`?