# How to insert a nice tilde in a lstlisting?

Tags: listings, tilde

How do I insert a nice tilde that is centered in the middle in a `lstlisting`? I found another thread about [tildes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex) but I can't apply it because the method described there only works outside of `lstlisting` as `lstlisting` displays all the text literally. Any ideas?

Here is how the tilde looks in my document at the moment - it's at the very top of the font and I would like it to be in the middle (like `~` this).

[image]

Here is the LaTeX for this fragment:

```
\section{Remove duplicate, consecutive lines (emulate "uniq")}

\begin{lstlisting}
awk 'a !~ $0; { a = $0 }'
\end{lstlisting}

Variables in Awk don't need to be initialized or declared before they are being used.
```

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312/correctly-typesetting-a-tilde

Answer (score 30):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    literate={~} {$\sim$}{1}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
awk 'a !~ $0; { a = $0 }'
\end{lstlisting}

Variables in Awk don't need to be initialized or declared before they are being used.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If `$\sim$` is too wide or prominent, then `\texttildelow` may be better. Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9365/120598

Comment: And, personally, an even better option is to do `\lstset{ literate={~}{{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\texttildelow}}}{1} }`, which raises `\texttildelow`. Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377/141755

Comment: I get `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]` after a substantial number of occurrences of `~` in a listing.  Is there a remedy for that?

Answer (score 12):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily]
awk 'a !~ $0; { a = $0 }'
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Peteris Krumins Have a look at this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc/677#677

Comment: @Peteris It uses a better fontencoding. But it is not the main point of Herbert's example. With beramono he changes to another typewriter font with a better looking tilde.

Comment: This looks awesome Herbert! No more `$\sim$` substitution for me---I wish I could upvote this answer twice!

Comment: I get `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]` after a substantial number of occurrences.  Is there a remedy for that?

Answer (score 10):

The above tip also works with T1 encoding and the `courier` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily]
awk 'a !~ $0; { a = $0 }'
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```