# lstlisting put '~' at the top of the line

Tags: listings

I use the package `listings` to add code snippet in my document. my problem is for the character `~`. It's placed at the top of the line, like if it was above a letter, while I want it at the middle of the line.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}

%%%
% For source code
%%%
\definecolor{mgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.4, 0.0}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=tblr,
  language=c++,
  basicstyle=\scriptsize,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  captionpos=b,
  showstringspaces=false,
  % Numbering
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{mgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{lstlisting}
class Foo {
public:

  // Constructor
  Foo();

  // Destructor
  ~Foo();
};
  \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a nice tilde in a lstlisting?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17266/how-to-insert-a-nice-tilde-in-a-lstlisting)

Comment: not exactly, I did a mix between the one you give and this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312/correctly-typesetting-a-tilde