# Why does ~ from Python file look so weird when imported into Latex?

Tags: listings, python

After inserting a Python file into my latex file via `\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{Thesis.py}`, I get

[image]

Normally, it should be `~`, but it is at higher than it should be. When I copy it from the output PDF , I no longer get `~`.

Could you please elaborate on this issue and how to get the normal `~`?

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17266/how-to-insert-a-nice-tilde-in-a-lstlisting help?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Because I imported via `\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{Thesis.py}`, the command in your linked answer does work. I mean I insert Python code and not directly type it in my LaTex document.

Comment: I don't think it matters that you're inputting a file. (And also,  if you thought that mattered, it would have been nice if your question included a minimal example in the first place, which would have definitely avoided any misunderstandings about what you're doing.) That said, I linked to a question, which answer doesn't work? The accepted answer worked for me with `\lstinputlisting`. So does the one with `beramono` and `fontenc`, but note that it needs `basicstyle=\ttfamily`.

Comment: I'm really sorry for my rush reaction @TorbjørnT. The one with `beramono` and `fontenc` does solve my problem.