# How to make tilde symbol in the center on the line text?

Tags: symbols, listings, tilde

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,breaklines=true,numbers=left,mathescape}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
clear all;
clc;
j=1;
if j~=1
    fprintf('j not equal to 1\n');
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Why the tilde symbol in `if j~=1` on the top? How to make it in the center on the line text?
[image]

Comment: That's probably because tilde is an accent If you want something centred on the math axis, why no use `$\sim$`?

Comment: @Bernard in a listing?

Comment: @albert: Oops! I only skimmed through the post and didn't see this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact the solution comes from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130513/231952, but it is part contained in a comment, so I thought it appropriate to summarize it here. (Other solutions here: [How to insert a nice tilde in a lstlisting?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17266/how-to-insert-a-nice-tilde-in-a-lstlisting.))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,breaklines=true,numbers=left,mathescape}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate={~}{{\raisebox{-.25em}{\textasciitilde}}}{1}}

\begin{document}
 \begin{lstlisting}
 clear all;
 clc;
 j=1;
 if j~=1
 fprintf('j not equal to 1\n');
 end
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

THIS?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,breaklines=true,numbers=left,mathescape}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate={~}{{\raisebox{-.25em}{\textasciitilde}}}{1}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{lstlisting}
 clear all;
 clc;
 j=1;
 if j\~=1
 fprintf('j not equal to 1\n');
 end
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding extra characters in a listing?

Comment: You have an extra character in the solution that is not supposed to be there. Also, it replicates the existing answer.