# How to insert LaTeX symbols?

Tags: symbols, tilde

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex)

I tried inserting symbols in latex. 
e.g.:
    `\texttildelow`

It didn't work.
But symbols like 
    `\textasciitilde`
work.

I can't understand why some symbols work and others (the first one mentioned here) result in "undefined control sequence" error.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Correctly typesetting a tilde](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312/5764), [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde into LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9363/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

these symbols need the `textcomp` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}%

\begin{document}
\texttildelow

\textasciitilde
\end{document}
```