# put a link in the document

Tags: verbatim, links

I'm using the following code snippet to put a link in the document:

```
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{verbatim}
http://vlm1.uta.edu/~zhangzhong/fall_detection/
\end{verbatim}
\end{footnotesize}
```

But the latex changed my link to:

> http://vlm1.uta.edu/˜zhangzhong/fall_detection/

It seems that it can't show '~' correctly.

Comment: Try packages `url` or `hyperref`

Comment: related/possible duplciate [Correctly typesetting a tilde](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312/correctly-typesetting-a-tilde)

Answer (score 6):

You could load the `url` (or the `hyperref`) package and issue the commands

```
{\footnotesize \url{http://vlm1.uta.edu/˜zhangzhong/fall_detection/}}
```

The `\url` command (a) renders its argument in a monospaced (aka typewriter) font -- as you are evidently trying to do by using a `verbatim` environment -- and, very importantly, (b) takes care to deal correctly with characters, such as `~`, that are "special" to TeX but are perfectly valid in URL strings.

Incidentally, there is no real `footnotesize` environment, just a `\footnotesize` switch. To limit the scope of this switch, use curly braces (as is done in the example above).

Comment: yeah, this kind of work. But you can't just click the link to show the webpage if using this way.

Comment: You can, if the `hyperref` package is loaded.